# showing continents programmatically in MKMapView

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, geocoding

I have a view with 3 buttons (Europe, Asia, America) and a MKMapView.
If one of these buttons was clicked, i need to show the specific continent.

In 
    `MKGeometry.h (Mapkit Framework)`
there is a constant
    `MKMapRectWorld`
which i can use to show the whole world.

Is there something similar for continents?
If not, what is the best way to determine all informations i need for creating a MKCoordinateRegion?

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Earth or Goole Maps to work out the lat/long boundaries and then call `setRegion` on your map view.